# Why is "would" used in "tasks that would not overwhelm them"?

Tags: usage, will-would

I find it very confusing to use '**would**' in sentences like:

> That's why they give beginner employers introductory tasks that **would** not overwhelm them.

Why is "would" used here?

Comment: which implies: if they were asked to do so. There is always an implied if in that usage.

Comment: Some auxiliary is necessary for the negative to follow. _Would_ is as good as any modal to indicate irrealis -- to show that the speaker is being hypothetical. The only other possibility is _do_, which indicates that the speaker knows something about how easy they are to overwhelm, so it's a present generic, referring to multiple experiences

Answer (score 1):

This is a sentence that uses **would** to refer to hypothetical situations.

We use **would** to make hypotheses:

1. When we imagine a situation:

- It would be very expensive to stay in a hotel.
- I would give you a lift, but my wife has the car today.

2. In conditionals:

- I would give her a call if I could find her number.
- If I had the money, I'd buy a new car.
- You would lose weight if you took more exercise.
- If he got a new job, he would probably make more money.

You could also write: **They give them tasks that will not overwhelm them**, which is more immediate.

The use of **would** fits better when talking about situations that are imagined, conditional or very general rather than specific.

[Source of examples](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/will-and-would)

Comment: No, it's not a sentence about things that happened in the past. **They give...** is present - and the sentence embraces actions in the past, present and future.

Comment: Okay. I understand. But it will be great help if you could modify my answer to improve it, like I don't know the exact words to re-frame the sentence as such.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you so much. I am grateful.